# Very basic using of VBA property

Tags: vba, properties

I would like to use this property:

```
Public Property Get HasNoData() As Boolean

   HasNoData = (numberOfColumns < 2 And numberOfRows < 2)

End Property

Sub test()

Dim numberOfColumns As Long
Dim numberOfRows As Long

numberOfColumns = 5
numberOfRows = 3

If HasNoData Then
MsgBox True
Else:
MsgBox False

End If

End Sub
```

Everytime I get **TRUE**, no matter whether the conditions are met or not. I might get the whole idea wrong, so please let me know.

Comment: Are you using this in a Class Module?

Comment: `MsgBox True` makes no sense. Also, `Else:` looks like a script label, not an `If..Else..End If` statement. I doubt this even compiles.

Comment: Please take a look at [cpearson's Classes In VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx).

Comment: No, I didn't. Now I put the property in a Class module, the Sub stayed as an Excel object and now it says **False**. MsgBox True could be MsgBox "Whatever1". Else: is the same as Else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that are wrong with your code as it stands now:

1. Properties can only be members of a class
2. Variables are subject to what is known as scope, and specifically your two variables `numberOfColumns` and `numberOfRows` are only available within the scope of the `test()` Sub, so they and their values cannot be seen inside the `HasNoData()` property unless they are passed as parameters or set as members of the class
3. The VBA `Msgbox` takes a String as the parameter, whereas you have provided a Boolean

I think what you really want is to make "HasNoData" into a function that takes two parameters, one for rows and one for columns.  Try this:

```
Public Function HasNoData(NumRows, NumCols) As Boolean
   HasNoData = (NumCols < 2 And NumRows < 2)
End Function

Sub test()
    If HasNoData(3, 5) Then
        MsgBox "There is data!"
    Else
        MsgBox "There is no data."
    End If
End Sub
```